# What is the proper transitionend (or animationend) that I need to apply?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

Okay Im mostly unsure how to use transitionend (or if Im supposed to use animationend in this case). Im unsure if Im supposed to use var, node or box. Pretty much Im a complete novice in this case.

Im trying to make it so my div animates a opacity transition for 1 iteration after a short delay from 0% opacity to 100% opactiy to 5% opacity. Then the second animation I want to delay to play just after the first animation is done and then do a lesser opacity shift for infinite iterations.

Heres the .css

```
.container{
    position: absolute;
    width: 224px;
    height: 220px;
    background-color: black;
}
.centerhex{
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/4sZDtfK.png);
    height:224px;
    width:210px;
    position:absolute;
}
.done{
    animation-delay:0.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:0.5s;
}
.transtart{
    opacity:0
}
.fadein{    
    animation:fadein 0.65s;
    animation-timing-function:linear;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    animation-iteration-count:1;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:1;
    -webkit-animation:fadein 0.65s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.pulse{ 
    animation:fadein 4s;
    animation-timing-function:linear;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    animation-delay:1s
    -webkit-animation-delay:1s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -webkit-animation:fadein 4s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein { 
    0%{opacity:0;}
    40%{opacity:1;}
    50%{opacity:1;}
    100%{opacity:0.05;} 
}
@keyframes fadein {
    0%{opacity:0;}
    40%{opacity:1;}
    50%{opacity:1;}
    100%{opacity:0.05;} 
}
@-webkit-keyframes pulse { 
    0%{opacity:0.05;}
    10%{opacity:0.1;}
    13%{opacity:0.1;}
    100%{opacity:0.05;} 
}
@keyframes pulse {
    0%{opacity:0.05;}
    10%{opacity:0.1;}
    13%{opacity:0.1;}
    100%{opacity:0.05;} 
}
```

Heres the HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="centerhex fadein transtart done"></div>
</div>
```

I put a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/2yLqj/

In my demo the "fadein" animation is the first animation, and the "pulse" animation is the second animation I want to attach. I did not add the pulse animation to the div because it breaks the intended effect.

I would greatly appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to have two animations with two different delays on the same div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20795412/trying-to-have-two-animations-with-two-different-delays-on-the-same-div)

Comment: it is a duplicate, sorry, deleting the other one because I did not know that it was a javascript question before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easiest to just use a `setInterval`, CSS transitions, and an if statement instead of mixing animations with javascript. Hopefully it's self explanatory

The only real CSS you need is `transition:opacity 2s ease-in-out;` on whatever class you're changing the opacity of. Here is the javascript

```
var origFadeVal = .05,
    newFadeVal = origFadeVal,
    fadeDepreciation = .9,
    fades = document.getElementsByClassName("fadein");

var animateOpacity = setInterval(function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < fades.length; i++) {
        if(fades[i].style.opacity == 1) {
            fades[i].style.opacity = newFadeVal;
            newFadeVal *= fadeDepreciation;
        }
        else {
            fades[i].style.opacity = 1;
        }
    }
    if(newFadeVal <= .005) {
        clearInterval(animateOpacity);
    }
}, 2000);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2yLqj/1/)

If you are looking to have an individual interval timing for each element of the class, you can use HTML5's `data-attribute`. [Here's a great article](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) on the subject for reference

In your case that'd mean creating a function that runs the `setInterval` for each element so you can use local variables. Again, the code should be fairly self explanatory but let me know if you have any questions

```
var origFadeVal = .05,    
    fadeDepreciation = .9,
    fades = document.getElementsByClassName("fadein");

for(var i = 0; i < fades.length; i++) {
    startInterval(fades[i]);
}
function startInterval(elem) {
    // Turn seconds into milliseconds using *1000, divide by 2 because we want it to run twice
    var intervalTiming = elem.dataset.intervalTiming * 500,
        /* Alternate form /* intervalTiming = elem.getAttribute('data-interval-timing') * 500, */
        newFadeVal = origFadeVal;
    elem.style.transitionDuration = intervalTiming;

    var animateOpacity = setInterval(function() {
        if(elem.style.opacity == 1) {
            elem.style.opacity = newFadeVal;
            newFadeVal *= fadeDepreciation;
        }
        else {
            elem.style.opacity = 1;
        }
        if(newFadeVal <= .005) {
            clearInterval(animateOpacity);
        }
    }, intervalTiming);
}
```

[**Demo with individual intervals**](http://jsfiddle.net/2yLqj/3/)

If you want an individual delay on the other hand, you can use a similar approach but use a `setTimeout`

[**Demo with individual delays and timings**](http://jsfiddle.net/2yLqj/6/) (**Fun one**)

If you just want the delay and all the same timings, I made a demo for that too:

[**Demo with individual delays**](http://jsfiddle.net/2yLqj/5/)

Hope this suits your needs!

Comment: This is a good solution, but unfortunately it wont work for what Im trying to accomplish. I have an array of these hexes all with individual delays associated with each one, so I need to have each class replaced after each hex reaches animation end. Here is a link to download an example of what I am currently working on: best viewed in FireFox (im still working out the kinks in chrome). https://www.dropbox.com/s/vwzbvvjo703ayv2/hexcenter.html

Comment: @JSArrakis You can use a `data-attribute` with the individual delays and do it for each. Tomorrow I'll update my answer with said way, going to bed now

Comment: Okay ill await that, and thank you so very much for your help!

Comment: @JSArrakis Updated with demos including the use of `data-attributes`

Comment: Thanks very much, now its time to analyze EXACTLY what you did so I can apply it in various areas.